# Make sure your questions don't get deleted silently: beware of Roomba!

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, roomba

Just a word of warning, as this SE is now over 1-year old: if you asked a question that is 1-year old, has no answer, didn't get any upvote and has at most 1 comment, [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/178179) will delete it without notifying you.

Comment: If your question has not received any attention in a year, you are strongly encouraged to edit it. Think what you could do to make the question more appealing: explain your use case more clearly, relax some requirements if you had a lot of them, or dually specify more precise requirements if what you had was vague, …

Comment: Nice gesture, Franck – but doesn't that somehow defeat the… errm… way this site is supposed to work? Feel free to upvote good questions anytime – but not for that reason (unless the OP has followed Gilles guidelines as outlined in the comment before mine ;) So maybe let's revert your suggestion to: Whenever you encounter such a question, feel free to post a comment to it so the OP can follow Gilles advice in time? :D

Comment: @Gilles I don't want to edit for the sake of editing. E.g. this [question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2263/903) seems perfectly OK as currently stated.

Comment: @Izzy Yes the point is precisely to defeat the purpose of Roomba... since another rule of SE is that we can use upvotes as we feel like :) No seriously I've lost dozens of questions because of this shit - which means hours waster -  before realizing its existence, so I'm quite mad at it to say the least.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because soliciting votes in this manner is not allowed and those engaging in this activity will likely get their account suspended or removed.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Given the amount of my questions who got deleted, I'm already getting a taste of getting one's account removed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I can appreciate your frustration, but all I can suggest is focusing on ***why*** those questions are getting little-to-no attention attention rather than gaming the voting system.

Comment: Just noting, 40% of the questions on this site have no answers to speak of. That could be because nothing really exists that meets what was laid out in the question, or .. perhaps .. the question just wasn't asked very well. I'd hate to see something half-ass get in the way of something that could actually be answered by getting votes and more exposure. Sure, the Roomba might not be completely fair in some very niche areas where nobody understands the question enough to realize it's useful, but for the most part, it's best left to do its thing.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Question edited to "respect the rules".

Comment: @RobertCartaino  I don't want to edit for the sake of editing. E.g. [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2263/903) seems perfectly OK as currently stated.

Comment: SR is not like other sites. Unlike other sites, 41% unanswered is normal (and expected) here. Roomba is designed for other sites, and should be disabled here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino How shall I further edit the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't know how to better ask your question. Folks may simply not have an answer. This is the go-to advice on that subject: **[How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/98786)**

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks the link. I see that this meta is now closed: how can I edit the question to make it on-topic?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Now that we elected you as one of our moderators, can you work with SE to remove Roomba on this site?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Would you mind posting an answer at http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/should-we-disable-roomba?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't mind.  Let me think a little about what to say.

Comment: Related: [How about archiving deleted posts in Wayback Machine?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254038/191655)

Comment: @kenorb thanks I had upvoted it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that some good questions escape our attention quickly, thus getting no upvotes and no answers. To spot these before they get Roombaed, I wrote this tool:

http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/284387/questions-needing-attention

It shows the list of zero-votes/zero-answers questions, oldest first.

So, please use this tool from time to time, and for each listed question, either upvote it or close it (or skip it if unsure, of course). Thank you!

Comment: Also: [New script: Questions needing attention](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1120/903)

Answer (score 11):

Soliciting votes in this manner goes against spirit of how we vet content, and we cannot allow this type of activity. While we encourage everyone to up-vote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, not some other criteria like the post's age or something like this vote-by-request.

I do not suspect completely ill intentions in what you are trying to do, but anyone saying *"contact me and I will up-vote your stuff"* would likely result in a lengthy suspension for all involved and may even get their account removed.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't upvote *any* question but only decent ones. I've added it in the question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That's just a bit of sophistry trying to work around the core issue. Saying "send me a link and I'll up-vote it (if its good)" isn't any more tenable than your original proposal. Please do not try to pursue this; actively undermining something as fundamental as voting is not going to end well.

Comment: I've already upvoted over half of the questions of this SE anyway (without being aware of roomba)... Feel free to undo if that's an issue.

Comment: How can you be a moderator with only 115 reputation and thus few badges? You cannot have been elected normally...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I am the Director of Community Development employed at Stack Exchange to oversee developing communities. That is how I have Moderator and administrative-level access.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Typically he has less than 100 as he tends to downvote more often than upvote. I never understood why Stack Exchange community managers do that.