# 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, December 7th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)

Answer (score 6):

> Do you think that the current policy of "delete-on-sight (with a comment)" for low quality answers should continue? What, if any, changes would you make / suggest?

Comment: Is the `any answer below that threshold will be commented upon asking for improvements, and then deleted if it fails to improve.` from [How are we going to moderate answers?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/305/2675) out of date??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ We've been operating on the highest-voted answer there (not the accepted one): http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/567/46 says "Any answer that consists solely of generic elements shall be summarily deleted".

Comment: Ahh - that explains it! Well, changes I'd suggest would be to use the accepted answer, purely because it gives a nicer impression to new users IMO. However, in some cases, when it's literally just a link, and it seems the answerer isn't going to put in any more effort, I'd agree to Gilles' suggestion, because the answerer does always have the option to repost.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 4):

What do you think this site's biggest challenge is? (E.g. post quality or quantity, too many/few closures/deletion, bad tools/guidance, etc.) What do you think should be done about it (by anybody: moderators, users in general, Stack Exchange staff, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new here, but I've participated in a couple of elections before, and a nice one to ask is:

> You close a question that's clearly off-topic and the user comes to Meta, not to ask what they did wrong, say you're a [mean word here]. How do you react?

Answer (score 2):

This site has the lowest [proportion of questions with an upvoted answer](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered). What do you think the cause is? Is this a problem, and if so what should we do about it?

Answer (score 0):

A moderator's votes are binding (aka „Thor's hammer“: if a mod votes to close, no other has to agree – the post is closed immediately). Will that change your voting behavior? Will you vote more/less/different?

Answer (score -2):

What to do to avoid [good questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/284387/questions-needing-attention) being deleted by [Roomba](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1116/903)?

Answer (score -4):

A question has the (accurate but not very precise) title “webapp to edit and share spreadsheets”. Explain in 600 characters or less what aspects are and are not on-topic.