# My question was automatically deleted what can I do?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81901/embarcadero-dev-c-portable-with-wxwidgets) I asked a year ago was automatically deleted. The questionwas was not downvoted nor was it closed, so I was surpised. Moderator told me it was Roomba cleanup. So since it´s unlikely the question gets undeleted, can I ask it again? Or what can I do?

Comment: Good meta question.  IMO, this particular Roomba is a bad, bad robot: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2460/8503

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket Have already read that question befor and upvoted your answer since I agree with it. But still wondering if I can now ask the question again.